# Xamarin forms TabbedPage Navigation between children

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating TabbedPage navigation in my project and I have button in page 1, when you click the button it must be go to page 2. It will slide on page 2 of the tabbedpage.

This is how i design my TabbedPage XAML

```
<TabbedPage
    android:TabbedPage.IsSmoothScrollEnabled="True" >

    <local:Home Title="Home"/>
    <local:MapsLocation Title="Map"/>
    <local:FeedbackPage Title="Feedback"/>
    <local:Profile Title="Profile"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

This is my code in my code in button command

```
public ICommand GotoCommand { get; }
private async void GotoExecute(object sender)
{
      var MyObject = (Shop)sender;
      await Navigation.PushAsync(new MapsLocation(MyObject.Address));
}
```

Page 1 when you click the button, It should be slide into the Page 2

Page 2, it should go here when you click the button in the page 1

It should be sliding into child 2 of TabbedPage

How do i achieve this?

Comment: in order to use `Navigation.PushAsync` you have to wrap your `ContentPage` in a `NavigationPage`

Comment: @Jason thank you for your response, but that's not what i need to achieve, i need to slide the page into the next page not actually pushing but sliding in the child of second page in TabbedPage, Sorry I'm not good in english, I tried wrapping it in navigation but it will go to another page inside the tabbedpage but i dont want that, i need to slide it to child next page on tabbedpage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58819109/8395242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to slide to other `Tabbedpage`, you can use the code below to achieve it. Note that the index of the tab.Children[index] starts from `0` and it should `<` the count of child tabbedpage or it'll throw the error `Index was out of range`.

```
private  void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var tab = this.Parent as TabbedPage;
    tab.CurrentPage = tab.Children[1];
}
```